# Fail to catch exception from proxy object under Xcode 3.2.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode3.2

I use HessianKit to communicate with server. In the situation of network or server down Hessian will throw exception, so I put every Hessian call in a @try ... @catch block. Everything worked fine until I upgraded Xcode from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3. I wrote the some testing code and found under Xcode 3.2.3, catch exception would be failed if the exception was thrown from a proxy object.

MyProxy.h:

```
@interface MyProxy : NSProxy {
}
@end
```

MyProxy.m:

```
@implementation MyProxy

- (id)init {
    return self;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    NSLog(@"Call method %@", NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]));
    [NSException raise:@"MyException" format:@"this is an exception"];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    .....
}

@end
```

Code using MyProxy:

```
@try {
    MyProxy *p = [[MyProxy alloc] init];
    [p doSomething];
    [p release];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"%@", e);
}
```

When these code build under xcode 3.2.2, the exception can be catched correctly. But under xcode 3.2.3, the program terminated after output following on the console:

```
2010-09-08 21:09:29.877 BriefCase[34651:40b] Call method doSomgthing
2010-09-08 21:09:29.879 BriefCase[34651:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MyException', reason: 'this is an exception'
2010-09-08 21:09:29.880 BriefCase[34651:40b] Stack: (
    45955152,
    47113004,
    45692683,
    45692522,
    151932,
    45426420,
    45423090,
    9352,
    4417860,
    4421967,
    4447550,
    4429047,
    4461016,
    53399932,
    45234332,
    45230248,
    4420129,
    4453234,
    8812,
    8666
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug with Apple, and the reply is:

It has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 7995323.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your project/target/executable settings have been messed up?
Is the "Enable Objective-C Exceptions" box ticked for your configuration/target/etc?

If it is, maybe you should file a bug with Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).

Comment: same code, same project configuration. I checked "Enable Objective-C Exceptions" box, it was ticked. Should I file a bug? I am an newer of Objective-C.

Comment: I would. I can't think of no reason it wouldn't work, if your test case is that simple.